# link two database tables

Tags: sql, database

A very quick question.  Is there a term for a table who's primary function is holding two foreign keys?  For example, if I have two tables, user and group, is there an official term for the "membership" table that holds user_id and group_id?

Comment: There's no official term - intersection, crossreference (xref), link, map, etc.  All are synonyms...  There's an SO question from 2009 or 2010 about this.

Comment: Thanks, i thought maybe an official term would make my tables names easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an intersection table which supports many-to-many relationships.

Comment: would you name the table, generically, user_group_intersection?

Comment: I would not normally include intersection in the name.  Something like user_group would be good.  Or even a UserGrouping, depending on your database naming conventions

Comment: Just noticed you beat me to it, I should've posted a quick answer before drawing the ERD haha

Comment: I don't need an ERD :)  I think the concept is very common and easy to understand.

Comment: Hence why I upvoted this answer ;) But it always helps me to visualize the data first

Comment: As far as naming convention goes, I definitely find it most useful to have the 2 names on the tables that this table is an intersection table for.  it makes things straight forward.  Some people like using names like UserGrouping in your situation, or membership - but I feel that those naming conventions obscure the underlying schema and are unnecessary.

Comment: See my comment to Dan's answer.  I'm having trouble coming up with a better example, but one can see that user_group can have its own meaning, especially when you start to have a lot of tables.

Comment: @Yitao Then you could have intersection tables leave out the underscore, or something along those lines.  Again, it is a matter of preference.  Maybe a prefix?  I_User_Group, but that would cause sorting issues when looking in your DB manager.

Answer (score 1):

A linking/intersection table, which resolves a many-to-many. For instance, if a car can have more than one driver, and a driver can have more than one car, you would use a linking table to resolve the many-to-many relationship. I drew an example ERD in OmniGraffle as an illustration:

[image: Example ERD]

Comment: There are several problems that can occur with the name table1_table2, especially when the table names that form the compound word makes sense on its own.  I would prefer disambiguating with a name like xref or link.  That was the point of my question.  Should have spelled that out better.

Comment: Yes, you certainly need to pick a convention that works for you. I've shown the standard convention I've seen most often, but I have definitely seen others.

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan Already answers: There are link/insersection tables for such a case. They will map many-to-many relations since there is no other possibilities in databases. You only have to create a table "UserGroup" and two columns for the specific ids which are both primary and foreign keys.