# sql database table creation

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am having trouble thinking of how I should build my simple database, its been about 3 years since I have done any sql dev which was back at uni so I have had habit of a brain fade.

I have two tables

- business
- customer

A customer can belong to many businesses and a business can have many customers.. so far I  have created this as a database..

The `Business` table looks like this

```
- id
- name
- address
```

`Customer` table:

```
- id
- name
```

My question is how do I link these two together, how do i keep track of which customers are with which businesses so if a customer joins a business do I need a new table that is like business id and customer id??? I'm just a bit lost, hopefully you guys get what I am asking.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to link just two tables. the link to this question will be a fit for you: [link two database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026755/link-two-database-tables/11026806#11026806)

Comment: so would I do something like, **customer**/**busniesses**/**joined** where joined is busniess id and customer id... dose that make sense?

Comment: yes something like that. mostly such link tables will be named with the entities names they will contain. in your case `CustomerBusiness` make sure to have both ids as pk and then each of them fk to their related tables

Comment: cool, thanks very much.. I was just struggling to think of this correctly, and then i was not very sure if it was an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the party model, with a relationship table. This lets you have individual or organization customers (or busineses) and multiple relationships between them:

```
PARTY
id
type: {individual, organization}
name

RELATIONSHIP
fromParty references PARTY
relationshipType: {customerOf, organizationalContactOf, leadOf, staffOf, vendorOf}
toParty references PARTY
```

Comment: okay, thanks for your reply.. I am still reading up about bits and pieces I will add this to the list as its outside anything I have done before with sql